# How to create a JavaScript Multiplication Table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying so hard to create a multiplication table that shows the results inside table cells and it generates a new table whenever you type a new number in the prompt dialog box. So far I have created the first row and the first colon. I have tried different ways to do the multiplication, but it does not work for me. Can you help me? (Down here you have the HTML, CSS and JS code.)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  while (true) {

    var $Number = prompt("Choose a number to create the Multiplication Table:");
    if ($Number === '' + parseInt($Number)) {
      break;
    } else {
      alert("You didn't type a number! Please type a number!");
    }

  }

  for (var a = 1; a < parseInt($Number) + 1; a++) {
    var cell = $("<td>" + a + "</td>");
    $("#row1").append(cell); //Krijon rreshtin e pare me numrat nga 1 deri ne $Number

    var colon = $("<tr> <td>" + a + "</t> </tr>").attr("class", a);
    $("table").append(colon); //Krijon kolonen e pare me numrat nga 1 deri ne $Number

  }

})
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 90%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
table {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 2em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
td {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>

  <h1> Multiplication Table </h1>

  <table border="1">
    <tr id="row1">
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hint: use nested loops, e.g. inside your `for a...` add a new `for b ...` loop. One loop builds the rows, the other one builds the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

#### Logic

Table is divided into 3 parts,

- top panel: "X" followed by numbers
- left panel: numbers only
- body: multiplication values.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/g9nvd6mj/)

```js
function createBody(num) {
  var _html = "";
  for (var r = 0; r < num;) {
    _html += "<tr>";
    _html += "<td>" + ++r + "</td>";
    for (var c = 1; c <= num; c++) {
      _html += "<td>" + r * c + "</td>";
    }
    _html += "</tr>";
  }
  return _html;
}

function createHeader(num) {
  var _html = "<tr>";
  _html += "<td>X</td>";
  for (var r = 1; r <= num; r++) {
    _html += "<td>" + r + "</td>";
  }
  _html += "</tr>";
  return _html
}

(function() {
  var n = window.prompt("Enter a number");
  var html = createHeader(n) + createBody(n);
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = html
})()
```

```css
table {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 2em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
td {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd
}
```

```html
<table id="content"></table>
```

**Note:** Its a bad practice to append elements in loop. You should create html string and perform a bulk operation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example using nested loops, as suggested by [mpf82](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4349415/mpf82).

```js
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var temp = '';
var max = parseInt(prompt("Type max number", "10"));
var t = new Date().getTime();
for (var y = 1; y <= max; y++) {
  var row = '<tr>';
  for (var x = 1; x <= max; x++) {
    row += '<td>' + (x * y).toFixed(0) + '</td>';
  }
  temp += row + '</tr>';
}
console.log(new Date().getTime() - t, 'ms to build string');
t = new Date().getTime();
table.innerHTML = temp;
console.log(new Date().getTime() - t, 'ms to append string');
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure JS may be you can do something like this by utilizing a `tableMaker` function. Table maker takes an array of objects and returns an HTML table string. Each object item of the array designate a row in the table where object properties designate columns. So for instance {a:1, b:2} would mean a row with two cells with values 1 and 2. Table headers would then be "a" and "b". All objects should have exactly same properties to prevent conflicts on header names or column counts.

```js
function tableMaker(o,h){
  var keys = Object.keys(o[0]),
  rowMaker = (a,t) => a.reduce((p,c,i,a) => p + (i === a.length-1 ? "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + "></tr>"
                                                                  : "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + ">"),"<tr>"),
      rows = o.reduce((r,c) => r + rowMaker(keys.reduce((v,k) => v.concat(c[k]),[]),"td"),h ? rowMaker(keys,"th") : []);
  return "<table>" + rows + "</table>";
}

function makeRow(i){
  var o = {},
      j = 0;
  while (j < size + 1) j === 0 ? o[j++]  = "<b>" + (i+1) + "</b>"
                               : o[j] = (i+1) * j++;
  return o;
}
var  size = 10;
tableData = new Array(size).fill().map((row,i) => makeRow(i));
myTable.innerHTML = tableMaker(tableData,true)
```

```html
<div id="myTable"></div>
```